# Keep a window On Top, even on top of other softwares in Full Screen, in windows?

Tags: windows-10

I work in a Citrix environment and that is in fullscreen.

However, my video meeting software (Zoom) is not in this Citrix environment and can't be, so I must run Zoom on my local computer. Problem is, I can't have both visible at the same time. I tried several tools to keep a window "Always on top" but it does not work on top of fullscreen windows.

Any idea?

I run on Windows 10.

Comment: Make sure your Task Bar is always visible. Almost everything (and certainly Zoom) goes there. The Task Bar is the best way to hover and find almost everything.

Comment: I do not see my local computer task bar anymore when I am in my Citrix environment.

Comment: Check Windows Settings, Personalization, Task Bar and make sure it has not been hidden. No Task Bar cripples your machine.

Comment: There are no such setting that affects my situation. The Citrix environment is in full screen and thus, my local environment's task bar is hidden (just as if you were watching a video on YouTube in full screen, it hides your task bar).

Comment: I suggest contacting Citrix Support.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Citrix. This is for any 'full screen' window. The question is how to keep a window (ex: Zoom) always on top of ANY screen, even full screen windows (like a Citrix window, or any other full screen window, like a YouTube Video, etc.)

Comment: I am not sure about your system - full screen apps allow my Task Bar to show.

Comment: Try doing a Windows Repair (Media Creation Link). Full Screen is working well on 3 machines here.

Comment: I came here to solve the same problem.  The only partial solution I've found is that citrix CAN be run as a window, if it is, then zoom can go always on top over it.  The problem is that if you have multiple monitors of different sizes that you are trying to run in Citrix, this won't help.  You can also run zoom on a phone or tablet.  So far though I haven't found an answer to our exact problem either.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a small [ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com) script:

```
#space:: Winset, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle, A
```

When you select desired window and press `windows` and `space` keys it will set it over all other windows. When you press the key combo again it will toggle it.